# count not move cursor to position 1 in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, android-emulator

I am developing an android app in which I am populating spinners from a SQLite database.
It has a simple form whose data is saved into a database table. I have kept an option to enable the user submit the form there itself.

So to get the id of the saved form i am moving the cursor to the last position. When I am trying to load the saved forms i am getting this error.

```
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988): java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't move cursor to position 1
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:178)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:192)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:151)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:115)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7192)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1243)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1049)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7192)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7192)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1304)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7192)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7192)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7192)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047) 
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7192)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7192)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1141)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1860)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-24 08:32:47.780: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3988):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It is not pointing to any specific error in my files.
I removed move to last position and it is working. So I kept as soon as I am done with getting data from the cursor I am moving it back to first position. Still not working

All the forms below the first form are working rest of the forms are not working :(

Please kindly help me out

Yours Sincerely,
ChinniKrishna Kothapalli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if (cursor != null) 
{
    try {
       while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
       {
        i = 0;
            // System.out.println(" =======> From DBConnect, Header => "+cursor.getString(1));
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.d("DB_SELECT_BUSINESS_EXCEPTION", "" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
       cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 if(cursor.moveToLast()){
                        }
```